# Moving my online only business to the USA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, start-up

I'm looking to form or purchase a US corporation (whichever is easiest/cheapest) (I'm thinking in Delaware) for the benefits of doing business as a US corporation. This corporation will be used to house an online only business with 1 physical office in the UK. I'm a UK citizen - non US resident / non US citizen. I will be selling my UK corporation to my US corporation for $1.00.

Do I need a Visa to own or purchase a US corporation? What other complications might there be in this process? e.g. Do I need a US physical office address on the US corporation documents?

Comment: This seems to be more of a legal questions than a finance question. One question I have is why do you want to have a US based business. Doing so will open you up to a lot of regulation that will be cumbersome to comply with.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Visa to create or own US property.

Your registered agent will be able to take care of most of this, and your new entity will use the registered agent's address where applicable, but you may need your own separate address which can be your office in the UK. If you want privacy then you'll want a separate address, which can also be a PO Box or an address the registered agent also provides.

US corporations, especially in Delaware, have a lot more compliance issues than the LLC product. Delaware has a lot more costs for formation and annual reports than most other united states. There are definitely a lot of states to choose from, but more people will have information for Delaware.